# How to I FTP files down from an Azure website

Tags: azure, ftp

I can get files uploaded from Visual Studio using publish and using my azure profile But now the website and my local files are not in synch. I need to download my site and I just don't see where to do that. Id like to use an FTP client to manage this.

Answer (score 6):

If you open up publish profile file, you should see information about FTP as shown below (see the 2nd `publishProfile` node):

```
<publishData>
  <publishProfile profileName="mywebsite - Web Deploy" publishMethod="MSDeploy" 
                  publishUrl="waws-prod-ch1-001.publish.azurewebsites.windows.net:443" 
                  msdeploySite="mywebsite" 
                  userName="$mywebsite" 
                  userPWD="jlnH6ZomzWS1njrsGyWfjgEbKER4W8XqZtLjx0fMPtuHMpk" 
                  destinationAppUrl="http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net" 
                  SQLServerDBConnectionString="" mySQLDBConnectionString="" 
                  hostingProviderForumLink="" controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com">
    <databases/>
  </publishProfile>
  <publishProfile profileName="mywebsite - FTP" publishMethod="FTP" 
                  publishUrl="ftp://waws-prod-ch1-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot" 
                  ftpPassiveMode="True" 
                  userName="mywebsite\$mywebsite" 
                  userPWD="jlnH6ZomzWS1njrsGyWfjgEbKER4W8XqZtLjx0fMPtuHMpk" 
                  destinationAppUrl="http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net" 
                  SQLServerDBConnectionString="" mySQLDBConnectionString="" 
                  hostingProviderForumLink="" controlPanelLink="http://windows.azure.com">
    <databases/>
  </publishProfile>
</publishData>
```

You could use that information to connect to the site via FTP.

Answer (score 0):

If you log into https://manage.windowsazure.com/ and look at the bottom right of your dashboard, you will see FTP information.

You can use this information in your favorite FTP client (e.g. FileZilla) to connect and both upload and download files from your Azure website.

It is mind numbingly easy.

[image]